# Sweeping out the disk: what comes out?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, geodesics, minimal-surfaces

In 2008, Larry Guth gave a new proof of a theorem of Gromov about the min-max widths of the unit $n$-ball. This states that the $p$-parameter width $\omega_p(k,n)$ (of sweepouts with $k$-dimensional surfaces) satisfies
\begin{equation}
 p^{1-k/n} / C \leq \omega_p(k,n) \leq C p^{1-k/n},
\end{equation}
where $C = C(n) > 0$ is a purely dimensional constant.

My question is about the simplest case, where one varies the number of parameters but keeps
\begin{equation}
k = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad n = 2
\end{equation}
fixed throughout. There $\omega_p := \omega_p(1,2)$ accordingly grows like $p^{1/2}$.

> For each value $p \geq 1$ the min-max principle applied to the $p$-parameter sweepout produces a geodesic net $G_p = (V_p,E_p)$ in the unit disk $B^2 \subset \mathbf{R}^2$ whose length is $\omega_p$. What do they look like? (Hunches or guesses are fine too!)

It seems even to come up with a natural sequence of geodesic nets whose lengths grow like $p^{1/2}$. The only examples I can think of will be based on unions of lines, and so would grow like $p$. Obviously that's much larger than the optimal sequence.